# How can I enable Emmet in Sublime Text 3 for Markdown?

Tags: markdown, sublimetext3, emmet

Recently, Emmets tab-expansion in Sublime Text 3 stopped working for me. I can still <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and enter: "Emmet: Expand abbreviation". But when I press just <kbd>TAB</kbd> it stopped working.

How can I trigger the abbreviation expansion with tab, being in a markdown file?

### What I tried

I added this to my keybindings, but it didn't have any effect:

```
{"keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually add markdown scope to Emmet settings.

1. Open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet -> Settings`.
2. Copy the `abbreviation_scopes` section from the left side to the right and add this line to it:

`"text.html.markdown",`

My user settings now look like this:

```json
{
    "abbreviation_scopes": [
        "text.html.markdown",
        "(text.html | text.xml) - source - meta - comment",
        "source.sass - meta.property-value - meta.property-name - string - punctuation - comment",
        "(source.css | source.scss | source.less | source.postcss | source.stylus) & meta.property-list",
        "(source.css | source.scss | source.less | source.postcss | source.stylus) - meta.property-value - meta.property-name - string - comment",
        "(source.tsx | source.js | source.jsx) - comment",
        "text.html.cfml - meta.tag",
        // Inline CSS
        "text.html meta.attribute-with-value.style (string.quoted | source.css)"
    ],
}
```

Tab expansions will now work in Markdown.